# Three different onclick events should show three different sets of slides of the same slider

Tags: jquery, html

I have a slider which becomes visible when the user clicks on an image map. I have 3 different image maps on my page and each should show a different group of slides when activated. Currently the slider shows the same slides for each of the image maps. How can I achieve this without having to create 3 different sliders. I was hoping to use one slider that picks out the correct slides when one of the image maps is clicked on. Enclosed is my html and js file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#slider_option').click(function(){
        $('#slider').css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#slider_option').css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#gallery1').fadeTo( 1200, 1,function(){

        });
    });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
            }, 200, function () {
                $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
                $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
            });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
            }, 200, function () {
                $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
                $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
            });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

    $('map').click(function(){

        $('#gallery1').fadeTo( 1200, 0 );
        $('#slider').css('visibility','visible');
        $('#slider_option').css('visibility','visible');


    });

});


And here is my html:


  <!DOCTYPE HTML>

 <html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>paulienlombard.com</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

     <script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

 </head>

 <body>

     <div id="container">

         <div id="content" class="clearfix">

             <div style="fgimg">


                 <img src="homepage_im.png" class="fgimg" alt="homepage" width="960" height="600"   usemap="#gallery" id="gallery1"/>

                 <map name="gallery" id="gallery">
                     <area shape="rect" coords="25,225,200,450" style="outline:none" href="#" alt="" />
                     <area shape="rect" coords="750,225,925,450" style="outline:none" href="#" alt="" />
                     <area shape="rect" coords="375,275,575,425" style="outline:none" href="#" alt="" />
                 </map>
             </div>    

         </div>

         <div id="header">

            <img src="logo_im.png" alt="Logo Paulien Lombard" id="logo">

         </div>

         <div id="slider" class="gallery">
             <a href="#" class="control_next">&gt;</a>
             <a href="#" class="control_prev">&lt;</a>
             <ul>
                 <li><img src="dog.png" class="slide" alt="dog" id="im6"></li>
                 <li><img src="disk.png" class="slide" alt="disk" id="im7"></li>
                 <li><img src="fruit.png" class="slide" alt="fruit" id="im8"></li>
                 <li><img src="garden.png" class="slide" alt="garden" id="im9"></li>
                 <li><img src="girl.png" class="slide" alt="girl" id="im10"></li>
                 <li><img src="vondel.png" class="slide" alt="vondel" id="im1"></li>
                 <li><img src="rome2.png" class="slide" alt="rome2" id="im2"></li>
                 <li><img src="room.png" class="slide" alt="room" id="im3"></li>
                 <li><img src="rome.png" class="slide" alt="rome" id="im4"></li>
                 <li><img src="berkeley.png" class="slide" alt="berkeley" id="im5"></li>
             </ul>  
         </div>

         <div id="slider_option">
             &#10005;
         </div> 

     </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Too much code in the question.  Have you considered a jsFiddle to illustrate the problem.  You should also describe what you have tried and what you have studied to get here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I have tried sofar doesn't amount to much. I am very new to jquery. My approach up to this point has been to search for existing answers to questions and I have had a lot of help from this site that way. With my limited knowledge I can only come up with creating 3 different sliders to achieve the above and I will do that if I don't get another suggestion. However, I am hoping that there is a more elegant way of doing things.

Comment: Our problem isn't our desire to assist in any way we can its is in the comprehension of how to do that.  You have posted a lot of code and are asking a general question on how to design an application.  I get the impression that you have some specific question in mind but it isn't coming through.  After re-reading, I'm still not sure what a "slider" is?  It may be very meaningful to yourself but it is not a core concept (at least to me) in web programming.

Comment: With slider I mean an image slide show. Currently I have this slideshow appearing on the page using jquery manipulating the css visibility property. By clicking any of the three image maps, the slide show appears. My objective is to make just certain slides appear by clicking on one of the three image maps as opposed to having all slides appearing when clicking on each of the image maps.

Comment: I think you have one image map which has three areas as opposed to three image maps?  Is that correct?  (breaking the puzzle down piece by piece).

Comment: Yes indeed, that is correct

Comment: BTW: Thanks for putting up with newbie behavior. Must be quite trying..

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/5w8v983c/) that shows a possible solution.  Rather than talk about slides and other items, let us think about images on the screen.  What we are saying here is that we want to only show a subset of possible images and not all of them based upon events.  In the sample, we have six images loaded into the screen but they are broken into three sets (groupings).  Depending on which button is clicked, the corresponding set will be made visible.

This is only one possible solution.  Other solutions could dynamically load the images only when the appropriate set is selected which would be more efficient however this gives an indication of the general notion.

The code code for this solution is:

```
$(function() {
    function hideAll() {
        $(".group img").hide();
    }

    $("#set1").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        $(".group .set1").show();
    });

    $("#set2").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        $(".group .set2").show();
    });

    $("#set3").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        $(".group .set3").show();
    });
});
```

which sets up callbacks for each of the three buttons which then uses class selectors to determine which groups to hide and show.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in this direction. I will let you know the result.

Comment: If images weren't part of an image slider, this would have been a great solution. However, since images are in a row inside an image slider I will have to resort to some other way around this. Thanks for the help.